# Is there any bank that allows foreigners to open accounts?

Tags: banking

Just a bit of background: I am Venezuelan and in my country we have a really complicated, bureaucratic, plain dumb and authoritarian currency trade. It is extremely difficult to convert your money to any foreign currency that made my life a lot difficult because I work mostly online and need a place to save my money (USD).
So I am wondering is there a way or a bank that would allow me to open an account even tho I'm not resident?
I would really appreciate whoever can put an input on this because I'm on my process to move out of the country and every country I want to go ask me to prove my funds and they don't accept PayPal or another kind of e-accounts.

Comment: Note that countries do things like this for the explicit *purpose* of making it hard to moving money out of that country, since it would make the economy even worse.  (Of course, the very poor economy that makes them implement those policies is why you want to take your money out...)

Answer (score 1):

Stripe Atlas helps with this. They form US companies for foreign solo entrepreneurs and get them US bank accounts.

Another thing to remember with banks though, it doesn't matter what the compliance documents say, money talks. So your troubles will more likely stem from the amount of money you need to put in banks, more so than what the rules are.